# Border With a Square

Tags: css

How do I add a square onto a border between a div and an image? The square will be position on the left or the right depending on the position of the text (if the text is aligned right, the square will be bottom left; if the text is aligned left, the square will be top right).

[image: square over border]

```css
.item {
  flex: 1;
  background: #8d0700;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}

.image img {
  width: auto;
  height: 450px;
  outline: 2px solid rgba(218, 236, 255, 0.6);
  outline-offset: -6px;
}

.name {
  height: 100px;
  text-overflow: wrap;
  background-color: #8d0700;
  color: #fff;
}

.bottomborder {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
}

.topborder {
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
}

.name .left {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.name .right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="w3-container w3-row-padding indexcontainer">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="w3-col l3 item">
      <div class="name bottomborder">
        <h3 class="right">Die Casting and Machining</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col l3 item">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </div>
      <div class="name topborder">
        <h3 class="left">Plastic Injection Products</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `pseudoelements`.

You can adjust the position as you need. I've used `calc()` here to take into account the width of the border.

```css
.item {
  flex: 1;
  background: #8d0700;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}

.image img {
  width: auto;
  height: 450px;
  outline: 2px solid rgba(218, 236, 255, 0.6);
  outline-offset: -6px;
}

.name {
  height: 100px;
  text-overflow: wrap;
  background-color: #8d0700;
  color: #fff;
}

.bottomborder:after,
.topborder:before {
  content: '';
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background: black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
}

.bottomborder {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.bottomborder:after {
  left: 3em;
  bottom: calc(-1.5em - 3px);
}

.topborder {
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}
.topborder:before {
  right: 3em;
  top: calc(-1.5em - 3px);
}

.name .left {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.name .right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="w3-container w3-row-padding indexcontainer">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="w3-col l3 item">
      <div class="name bottomborder">
        <h3 class="right">Die Casting and Machining</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col l3 item">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </div>
      <div class="name topborder">
        <h3 class="left">Plastic Injection Products</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much! That worked perfectly! Is there a method to figuring out what the calc values are?

Comment: (half the elements height - half the border width) - Really, the only reason I used calc was I was using `em` units. If you set the pseudoelements height and width in pixels you can do without it.